# How to use GNU mtools to extract all files from a given disk image?

Tags: command-line, dos, gnu, disk, gnu-toolchain

I understand that [GNU mtools](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/mtools.html) can be used to extact files from a DOS disk image.  The example provided on the website shows how to extract a discrete number of files or directories from a disk image.

```
mcopy -i my-image-file.bin ::file1 ::file2 .
```

> This copies file1 and file2 from the image file (my-image-file.bin) to
>   the /tmp directory.

How do I use this command to extract all files from an image (recursively)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/html_node/mcopy.html it should be possible

> mcopy [-bspanvmQT] [-D clash_option] sourcefile [ sourcefiles… ]
>   targetdirectory
>
> ...
>
> s    Recursive copy. Also copies directories and their contents
>   p    Preserves the attributes of the copied files
>
> ...

But it doesn't mention the `-i` in your example.

Comment: The mtools documentation is a complete mess. Yes, it doesn't document -i there because there is a special section for arguments common to all tools. See here for -i: https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/html_node/drive-letters.html#drive-letters